# getting error "list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay so the code is

```
    Pdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75), round(x*1.0)))(['stats']['PStrength'])
    Mdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75), round(x*1.0)))(['stats'['PDexterity'])
    HP = 4 * ['lvl'] * ['stats']['PVitality']
    Mage = {'name' : 'Mage',
    'Class' : 'Player',
    'Sub-Class' : 'Mage',
    'lvl' : 1,
    'xp' : 26,
    'lvlNext' : 25,
    'Weak' : {'Lightning'},
    'Normal' : {'Shock'
                'Burn'
                'Water'
                'Freeze'},
    'Resistance' : {'Ice'
                    'Fire'},
    'Null' : {'Poison'},
    'stats': {'PStrength' : 5,
            'PProsperity' : 5,
            'PDexterity' : 15,
            'PVitality' : 5,
            'PAgility' : 10,
            'hp' : 'HP',
            'MP' : 50}}
```

and I'm getting the error "list indices must be integers, not str" how do I fix this?
(Also I've read through some of the posts that had problems like this and they really didn't help me, so please don't send me to another post.)

Comment: convert them to int?

Comment: @minitoto: I think the problem is more severe, unfortunately.

Comment: It's unclear what your code is trying to do.  Can you explain in text (not code) what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Garrett R I'm trying to make the characters health be calculated and I kept getting an error

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
['stats']['PVitality']
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
my_list = [
    'stats'
]
my_list['PVitality']
```

It was hard to tell you how to fix this until the edit, but now I see the data structure you are using.

You want something like this:

```
Mage['stats']['PStrength']
```

Although `Mage` must be defined before you use it.

### Minor note

Idiomatic Python would not use `lambda` here, since all `lambda` is doing is avoiding the leak of a temporary variable into the enclosing scope.  More idiomatic would be something like:

```
x = Mage['stats']['PStrength']
Pdmg = round(x*0.75), round(x*1.0)
```

Or something like:

```
def stat_damage(stat):
    """Calculate damage (foo, bar) from stat value."""
    return round(x*0.75), round(x*.10)
```

However, code style is a matter of taste and the `lambda` does function correctly here.  It will just be a bit of a surprise to other Python programmers.

Comment: Okay, I'll add more detail. @Dietrich Epp

Comment: and the lambdas were a suggestion because I asked someone else on here and that's what they suggested to do

Comment: okay thanks, i didn't show this but there are two more character dictionaries, could show me a way to do it with multiple dictionaries? @Dietrich Epp

Comment: @TylerTheHero: It sounds like you might need general programming help, with things like what variables are, what dictionaries are, etc.  There are a lot of great tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious answer is to quit using strings as list indices.  If **stats, PStrength**, and their cognates are variables, just remove the quotation marks.

You also have to supply the name of the list you're trying to index.

---

Your recent edit is a great improvement.  There are two critical, fatal problems with this:

1. Your code tries to get things out of the dictionary before it's initialized.
2. You don't give the dictionary name in the reference.

Fixing these ...

```
Mage = {'name' : 'Mage',
        'Class' : 'Player',
        'Sub-Class' : 'Mage',
        'lvl' : 1,
        'xp' : 26,
        'lvlNext' : 25,
        'Weak' : {'Lightning'},
        'Normal' : {'Shock'
                    'Burn'
                    'Water'
                    'Freeze'},
        'Resistance' : {'Ice'
                        'Fire'},
        'Null' : {'Poison'},
        'stats': {'PStrength' : 5,
                  'PProsperity' : 5,
                  'PDexterity' : 15,
                  'PVitality' : 5,
                  'PAgility' : 10,
                  'hp' : 'HP',
                  'MP' : 50}}

Pdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75), round(x*1.0)))(Mage['stats']['PStrength'])
Mdmg = (lambda x: (round(x*0.75), round(x*1.0)))(Mage['stats']['PDexterity'])
HP = 4 * Mage['lvl'] * Mage['stats']['PVitality']

print Pdmg, Mdmg, HP
```

Output:

```
(4.0, 5.0) (11.0, 15.0) 20
```

I also repaired the missing left bracket in the **Mdmg** line.

Comment: I'm still learning python (I'm learning as I go along) I'll provide more details and hopefully you'll be able to show me what you're talking about, I'm trying to reference a dictionary.

Comment: thanks, and the reason i didn't put the dictionary name in with the ['stats']['PDexterity'] was because i wanted it to work for multiple dictionaries

Comment: That's what a variable name is for.  Better yet, make this a function, with the dictionary as a parameter.

Comment: okay thanks, where do I put the parameters in the definition because I googled for it and I can't find where they go

Comment: We like helping people, but sometimes the person needs to help themselves first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone they know who can help them.  Instead of just using a search engine, how about walking through a Python tutorial?  There are many of those on line; you can search for *that* and solve not only the one question, but many more (some of which are already represented in this question).